# Composer Rest Server not returning what is annotated in model file

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have a Hyperledger Composer project where I want to return a generated id from a transaction. Here is the relevant portion of the `model.cto` file:

```
@returns(String)
transaction SetupGame {
  o PlayerTotem[] players
}
```

And here is the transaction in `script.js`:

```
/**
 * Setup Game transaction
 * @param {org.pandemic.board.SetupGame} txData
 * @returns {String} The string
 * @transaction
 */

function setupGame(txData) {
    let totems = txData.players;

    return getAssetRegistry('org.pandemic.board.Board').then((registry) => {

        let factory = getFactory();
        let NS = 'org.pandemic.board';

        let boardId = generateId();

        let board = factory.newResource(NS, 'Board', boardId);
        let boardCities = buildBoardCities(factory, NS);

        board.cities = boardCities;

        let infectionCards = buildInfectionCards(factory, NS);
        board.infectionCards = shuffle(infectionCards);

        let playerCards = buildPlayerCards(factory, NS);
        board.playerCards = shuffle(playerCards);

        let playerTotems = buildPlayerTotems(totems, factory, NS);
        board.players = playerTotems;

        return registry.add(board).then(() => {
            return Promise.resolve(boardId);
        });

    });
}
```

I tried to follow the convention set forth in the Composer reference for how the JSDoc should be in script file [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/js_scripts):

```
/**
 * Setup Game transaction
 * @param {org.pandemic.board.SetupGame} txData
 * @returns [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/string) The string
 * @transaction
 */
```

But when I had the `@returns` annotation set up like that, `composer archive create` would throw a malformed JSDoc error, so I changed it to `@returns {String} The string`

I expect to get the boardId back as the result of the transaction, but instead I just get the transaction back:

```
{
  "$class": "org.pandemic.board.SetupGame",
  "players": [
    {
      "$class": "org.pandemic.board.PlayerTotem",
      "totemName": "Daniel",
      "currentLocation": "Atlanta",
      "role": "MEDIC",
      "cards": [],
      "actionsRemaining": "4"
    }
  ],
  "transactionId": "a87b071c78e00617430ca4e6e189a984feb41a8e2f5ae101e0d73eb4d172d927"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see this issue in GitHub about the same problem.

https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/4245

The code provided by the contributer has been merged so it will appear in a Composer release soon.  Possibly later this week or otherwise next week.